# Can I reuse the 4 way handshake on my WPA2 network?

Tags: wireless-networking

Based on my other [Question](https://superuser.com/questions/1429834/wifi-ids-monitor-mode-vs-promiscous-mode-seeing-east-and-west-traffic/1429909#1429909), I am able to decrypt my WPA2 traffic. I captured the 4 way handshake and know the PSK. I used the Aircrack suite.

My goal now is to continuously dump traffic and decrypt it. I was thinking I would run airodump-ng and airdecap-ng in tandem in a script  and kill the former when the pcap hits a certain size and delete it.

But I may not always capture the 4 way handshake when I am not home. I *could* deauth in the script and then capture but it seems easier to try to reuse what I already have captured. Can I reuse the  4 way handshake like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't reuse the 4-way handshake. The reason you have to capture it each time is that they contain two nonces (two one-time-use random numbers) that are randomly generated each time a client joins or rejoins a network. These nonces are used along with the PSK to derive the unique keys that will only be used for this one session of this one client.

Comment: ok so it sounds like if I have 10 wireless clients, I need to capture 10 4-way handshakes as well to decrypt their traffic as well.